# In variadic JavaScript functions, when would one use the arguments object instead of rest parameters?

Tags: javascript

The arguments object behaves as follows:

```
function myFunc1(a, b, c) {
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  // expected output: 3

  console.log(arguments[1]);
  // expected output: 2

  console.log(arguments[2]);
  // expected output: 1

  console.log(arguments.sort());
  // expected output: "VM427:11 Uncaught TypeError: arguments.sort is not a function"
}

myFunc1(3, 2, 1);
```

Rest parameters behave as follows:

```
function myFunc2(...args) {
    console.log(args[0]);
  // expected output: 3

  console.log(args[1]);
  // expected output: 2

  console.log(args[2]);
  // expected output: 1

  console.log(args.sort());
  // expected output: [1, 2, 3]
}

myFunc2(3, 2, 1)
```

Rest parameters enable the passing of arguments as an actual array, including its prototype methods, rather than the arguments pseudo-array, without them.

Except for compatibility reasons (rest parameters were introduced in ES6), are there cases wherein one would use the arguments object instead of rest parameters?

Comment: Given that `args` doesn't exist in that first example, why would you expect that error?

Comment: That was a typo. Please check the updated question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#the_difference_between_rest_parameters_and_the_arguments_object

Comment: @WiktorZychla ... I think the OP is well aware of the differences. And since most uses cases hardly ever make use of `arguments`' sole specific `callee` property, the OP's subtile hint towards vanishing use cases for `arguments` is more than valid.

Comment: Correct. I read the MDN page on rest parameters + a few other resources on rest parameters/the arguments object, which left me wondering whether there would be any case (assuming ES6 compatibility is not an issue) where one would prefer using the arguments object.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to my mind is if you have something like this as the signature `function myFunc2(a1, a2, ...args)` and you want to pass all arguments to another function:

```
function myFunc2(a1, a2, ...args) {
   // so something based on a1, a2 or args

   // pass all arguments to another function
   anotherFunc(...arguments);
}
```

You for sure could write: `anotherFunc(a1, a2, ...args);`, but maybe `anotherFunc(...arguments)` expresses more that you are forwarding all arguments of `myFunc2`